# Tensorflow tf.scatter_update does not update float value

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems like tf.scatter_update does not update the variable if the type of the variable is defined as float. Here's a code you can try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def cond(size, i):
    return tf.less(i,size)

def body(size, i):
    b=2*7.5+c

    with tf.variable_scope("a", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

        a = tf.scatter_update(a,i,b)

        with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
            return (size, i+1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c=tf.constant(4.0)
    i = tf.constant(0)
    size = tf.constant(6)
    _,i = tf.while_loop(cond,
            body,
            [size, i])

    a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([a,i]))
```

The result would be random ! since I did not initialize the variable on purpose to see how it gets updated, it seems that it never gets updated and the random initialization would be printed out every time. You would see something like this:

[array([-0.35466522,  0.44001752,  0.21131486, -0.48532146,  0.3019274 ,
       -0.19926369], dtype=float32), 6]

Is this a bug ? as you can see, I am still using the tf.control_dependencies and it only happens if the type of the variable a is set to float.

Answer (score 0):

Is your expected output this ?

```
[array([19., 19., 19., 19., 19., 19.], dtype=float32), 6]
```

These two patterns produce that.

#### Pattern 1

```
import tensorflow as tf

def cond(size, i):
    return tf.less(i,size)

def body(size, i):
    b=2*7.5+c

    with tf.variable_scope("a", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

        a = tf.scatter_update(a,i,b)
        with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
            return (size, i+1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c=tf.constant(4.0)
    i = tf.constant(0)
    size = tf.constant(6)
    _,i = tf.while_loop(cond,
            body,
            [size, i])

    with tf.variable_scope("a", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess.run(init)

        print(sess.run([a,i]))
```

#### Pattern 2

```
def body(size, i):
    b=2*7.5+c

    a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

    a = tf.scatter_update(a,i,b)
    #Reuse variables 
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

    with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
        return (size, i+1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c=tf.constant(4.0)
    i = tf.constant(0)
    size = tf.constant(6)
    _,i = tf.while_loop(cond,
            body,
            [size, i])

    a = tf.get_variable("a",[6],dtype=tf.float32)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    print(sess.run([a,i]))
```

Comment: It seems like a bug if the code is run on a GPU. On CPU, it works nicely !

Comment: If this detail wasn't part of the question you can add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered much better [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23333) as a GitHub Tensorflow issue.

I'll try to summarize the tread here. There are two main issues:

1. When variable `a` is retrieved before running the session, it must be under the variable scope "a", otherwise you're creating a new variable. As @MohanRadhakrishnan mentioned.
2. `sess.run([a,i])` does not define the evaluation order of `a` and `i`. `a` can be evaluated either before, after, or during the loop, and before the loop `a` is randomly initialized. Therefore you can get different results. Thus, in this case the order must be defined by running `sess.run(i)` before running `sess.run(a)`. This can cause more issues on GPU due to more parallelization.

So the code will be:

```
def cond(size, i):
    return tf.less(i, size)

def body(size, i):
    b = 2 * 7.5 + c

    with tf.variable_scope("a", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        a = tf.get_variable("a", [6], dtype=tf.float32)

        a = tf.scatter_update(a, i, b)

        with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
            return (size, i + 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    c = tf.constant(4.0)
    i = tf.constant(0)
    size = tf.constant(6)
    _, i = tf.while_loop(cond,
                         body,
                         [size, i])

    with tf.variable_scope("a", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):  # Issue 1. Reuse 'a'.
        a = tf.get_variable("a", [6], dtype=tf.float32)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(i))  # issue 2. Define the order of operation.  
    print(sess.run(a))
```